# Trouble linking/compiling Libcurl in Eclipse IDE C++ Project

Tags: c++, eclipse, compiler-construction, linker, libcurl

Hi I am having trouble configuring an Eclipse C++ (32bit) project to use libcurl. I am using MinGW. I am on a 64bit windows OS. I have done the following so far:

- Add "libcurl.lib" to the project's **Libraries**
- Add the path of libcurl.lib to the **Library Paths**
- Add the path to the curl header files to the **Includes** path
- In source, I included "curl/curl.h"

However, I am seeing the following message:

```
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ "-LC:\\projectsrc\\Network\\curl-7.34.0-win32\\lib" "-LC:\\projectsrc\\Network\\curl-7.34.0-win32\\dlls" "-LC:\\projectsrc\\Network\\curl-7.34.0-win32\\bin" -o TestLibCurl.exe "src\\TestLibCurl.o" "-lC:\\projectsrc\\Network\\curl-7.34.0-win32\\lib\\libcurl.lib" 
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lC:\projectsrc\Network\curl-7.34.0-win32\lib\libcurl.lib
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Below is the sample source

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>

#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
     cout << "test" <<< endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Below is a screenshot of where I added the include path and the library file:

[image]

For your reference, I have **uploaded my sample C++ eclipse project** to dropbox here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2jowlkz6qypqe9g/TestingLibCurl.zip

The project file includes **main.cpp**, the **libcurl.lib** file, the **libcurl header files**, and the eclipse project setting files (**.cproject, .project, .settings**)

Oddly, I am able to get this to work in CodeBlocks IDE, using the same MinGW and using the same computer (Windows 64 bit). Do I need to add linker/options/flags when using Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Hi all I have uploaded my sample C++ eclipse project to dropbox here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2jowlkz6qypqe9g/TestingLibCurl.zip